# Cannot apply Indexing with [] to an expression type application.MatrixVariables

Tags: c#, arrays, struct

New to programming and trying to get my head around arrays and structures. I seem to be having an issue with the array and am not sure I am doing this correctly.

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{    
   public struct MatrixVariables
   {
       public int x, y;
       public MatrixVariables (int lowerV, int upperV)
       {
           x = lowerV;
           y = upperV;
       }
   }

   class Program
   {
       static void Main(string[] args)
       {
           int[,] a = new int[,] { { 0, 1, 1, 0 },{0,0,1,0}, {1,0,1,1}, {1,1,1,1}, {1,0,0,1} };
           int[,] t = new int[,] { { 30, 10, 50, 25, 14 } };
           MatrixVariables upperV = new MatrixVariables();
           MatrixVariables lowerV = new MatrixVariables();

           int maxP = 6;
           int maxV = 6;
           int p = 0;
           int v = 0;
           for (p=0;p<maxP;p++)
           {
               for (v=0; v == maxV;v++)
               {
                   if (a[p,v] ==1)
                   {
                       if (upperV[v] > t[p])
                       {
                           upperV[v] = t[p];
                       }
                   }
               }
           }   
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: What do you *expect* the indexer to do?

Comment: What is the issue? you havent listed one

Comment: @BugFinder: The error message is in the title, although the post could certainly be clearer.

Answer (score 0):

You declare `MatrixVariables upperV = new MatrixVariables();`

this is not really different to `int i = new int();` you have asked for a single sized chunk of your struct. Therefore it cant have sub parts.

Your structure is of `UpperV.x` and `UpperV.y`, not an array of anything. Both x and y will be zero, as you havent called your creator. But you havent used x or y for anything either, even if it was an array of.

Comment: if (upperV[v] > t[p])
                        {
                            upperV[v] = t[p];
                        } It is this line here. Giving the error message in the title. I don't really understand your answer. Do you have an example in code?

Comment: exactly but its not an array - you didnt ask for one.......... so you cant do that.. that also isnt setting the 2 variables in that structure, of x or y..  Youve also said that you're looping for 0->4 when the arrays in a are 4 items long not 5.......theres just a lot wrong there.

Comment: So do lowerV and lowerV need to be arrays instead of structs?

Comment: well as it stands your code will fail on a number of levels. You havent got code for lowerV .. what exactly are you trying to do?